# Pytube download bytes remaining not accurate/very slow

Tags: python, tkinter, download, pytube

I'm currently programming a YouTube Downloader with Pytube and Tkinter. After I finished programming the GUI I noticed that the bytes remaining coming from the progress function during the Download need way longer than the actual download itself (the finished file is already there while the progress bar still prints out the progress for sometimes over a minute)

What's weird about this is that it worked perfectly fine yesterday. That's why I tried out a simple program without any GUI and i still have same problem.

```
import pytube

def on_progress(stream, chunk, bytes_remaining):
    print(bytes_remaining)

def on_complete(stream, file_path):
    print("Finished")

video = pytube.YouTube("MyLink", on_progress_callback=on_progress, on_complete_callback=on_complete)
video.streams.get_highest_resolution().download(output_path="C:/My/Path")
```

I worked on the program for the past few days and did many test tries. Could be the reason that I tried downloading too many videos over a small period of time so Pytube is kind of overloaded?

Comment: Internet speed can flucuate and cause the download to lag, so could "many test tries" - might be worth changing your IP Address (might be logged on YouTube) and clearing whatever caches your code uses (if any)

Answer (score -1):

I see that you are using the **PyTube** library which uses **youtube-dl.exe** which is probably outdated now.

So instead of using the **PyTube** library, you should use
**yt-dlp.exe** which you can download [here.](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl)

You can read through the documentation on how to use it and if you still face problems using it then feel free to ask. I have a good experience of this stuff.